# ProgressDialog is not dismiss

Tags: android

I am making a web view and trying to show loading message using progress Dialog.progress dialog is showing but not dismissed after all the content of URL is loaded.Please Help me.

```
    mWebview  = new WebView(this);
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
    final Activity activity = this;
    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        ProgressDialog prDialog;
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            prDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Web.this, null, "loading, please wait...");
            super.onPageStarted(mWebview, url, favicon);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "started!"+1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            num++;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(mWebview, url);
            prDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String   failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    setContentView(mWebview);
```

Comment: Is `onPageFinished` getting called? Do you see the "Done" toast?

Comment: yes...@jason g peterson

Comment: yes it is showing "Done" toast message.

Answer (score 1):

```
    package com.example.webviewtag;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewDemo extends Activity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  WebView webView = new WebView(this);
  webView.setClickable(true);
  webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
  WebClientClass webViewClient = new WebClientClass();
  webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
  WebChromeClient webChromeClient=new WebChromeClient();
  webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
  setContentView(webView);
 }

 public class WebClientClass extends WebViewClient {
  ProgressDialog pd = null;

  @Override
  public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
   super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
   pd = new ProgressDialog(WebViewDemo.this);
   pd.setTitle("Please wait");
   pd.setMessage("Page is loading..");
   pd.show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   super.onPageFinished(view, url);
   pd.dismiss();
  }
 }

 public class WebChromeClass extends WebChromeClient{
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
private class MYWEBCLIENT extends WebViewClient {

    private ProgressDialog prDialog;

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        prDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Please wait...");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if (prDialog != null && prDialog.isShowing())
            prDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Load webview code,

```
webViewInfo.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webViewInfo.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webViewInfo.setWebViewClient(new MYWEBCLIENT());
webViewInfo.loadData("YOUR_URL_OR_HTML_FILE", "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this java code:

Just need to replace my entities with yours. Such as class name or other variables or stuff.

```
 public class WebViewDemo extends Activity
 {

   WebView mWebview;
   ProgressDialog prDialog;

   @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") 
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.web);

     mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
     mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

     CustomWebClient webClient =new CustomWebClient(WebViewDemo.this);
     mWebview.setWebViewClient(webClient);
     mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

 }

 // This is your custom webviewclient

 public class CustomWebClient extends WebViewClient 
{
    public Context context;

    public CustomWebClient(Context context) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        prDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        prDialog.setMessage("loading please wait...");
        prDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        prDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        try 
        {
            if ((prDialog != null) && prDialog.isShowing()) 
            {
                prDialog.dismiss();
            }
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException ae) {
        } catch (final Exception excep) {
        } finally {
            prDialog = null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
            HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(view, handler, host, realm);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
  }
 }
```

You can run my java class to test, is it working or not at your end.

Hope this helps you.